# socket_read only returns the 1st character

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, network-programming, server

I see that similar question has been asked several times but I don't see any answer working for me. I am trying to listen a port on my localhost with php using socket_read command and write the message to the server. The code works fine but I can only read and write only the 1st character. Say the client send *"hello"*, `socket_read` only reads the *"h"*.

```
$result = socket_read ($client, 1024);

echo "Reply From Server  :".$result ."\n";
```

It almost looks like php runs so fast that as soon as socket read receives the first character the program continues to run the next line. I need socket_read to wait until the message is over or certain character is seen in the message like space or period or dollar sign or whatever.

So far I tried ;

1. Used the socket read in a loop so everytime a character is received I can put in an array and eventually make the word *"hello"*. Did not work. When I use the loop I receive hundreds of null characters in seconds.
2. Reading PHP manual I tried to use `PHP_NORMAL_READ` in the heading. When this option is used socket_read should continue until the message has `\n` or `\r` but it does not how it works for my application.
3. I see that using node.js or websocket  was advised but they wont work and also this is not a chat platform. All I need to have is having a php script running on my web-site and when a client sends an information I would like the php script to be able to record that message in the sql server.

*Note*: I have tested remote and localhost connections. There is no difference. Also there is no problem with recording the message to the server. Only problem is receiving single character with `socket_read`.

Comment: I think you need to post more code.  TCP may appear as a byte-stream but it's packet-based underneath.  Assuming the client is sending "hello" in a single OS write, all 5 characters will be received simultaneously and made available to your program at the same time.